# How to use the same variable to store the return value of setInterval() and pass as parameter to clearInterval()?

Tags: typescript, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to use the same variable to store the return value of `setInterval()` and then pass it as an argument to `clearInterval()` in TypeScript. However, `setInterval()` returns `NodeJS.Timer` while `clearInterval()` takes `number`.

This is how I want the code to look like:

```
itemCooldownInterval: NodeJS.Timer | undefined;

this.itemCooldownInterval = setInterval(this.tickCooldown, 1000);
```

This is how I want to clear the interval:

```
clearInterval(this.itemCooldownInterval);
```

Answer (score 1):

The return values of setInterval in the Browser and Node.js are different. On what platform are you developing?

On the browser the return type is `number`. You're IDE might say something different, then just use `window.setInterval` instead.

```
itemCooldownInterval: number | undefined;

// this will work
this.itemCooldownInterval = window.setInterval(this.tickCooldown, 1000);
```

Either way you can use `ReturnType` to infer the matching type:

```
itemCooldownInterval: ReturnType<typeof setInterval> | undefined;
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I want `itemCooldownInterval: NodeJS.Timer | undefined;` not `itemCooldownInterval: number | undefined;`

The environment is NodeJS, so I can't use `window.setInterval(this.tickCooldown, 1000);`

Comment: And your code is not working? Whats the error message?

Comment: When I set `itemCooldownInterval`'s type as `NodeJS.Timer`, `clearInterval` complains and says `Type Timer is not assignable to type number`. When I set it to `number`, I get the same error if I do this: `this.itemCooldownInterval = setInterval(this.tickCooldown, 1000);`.

Comment: So this is a (server-side) node project - not a browser project, correct? It should be working then :/